# Several processes are listening to the same interface: any problem?

Tags: packet

I wonder if some processes may get less packets than others if they are all listening to the same wireless interface.

I'm running for example the basic mitm schema using `arpspoof`, sniffing packets with `ettercap`, running `urlsnarf` to see some GET requests and `tcpdump` saving the dump packets into a file. All in different terminals listening to `wlan0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packets are received by the kernel, and given to all applications who request them. You may lose some packets only if you run out of processing resources: if you do some heavy treatments and don't have enough CPU / RAM / disk bandwidth to process all the incoming packets. At that point, buffers will overflow, and some applications will miss some packets (from the kernel point of view, the packet was made available, but some application did not obtain it in time, and the packet has to be evicted to make room for subsequent packets).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I mark it as answered. Mark's answer was also helpful.

Comment: In other words.... https://imgflip.com/i/b30pu

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the network stack was competently programmed, no.  An interface in monitor mode should hand off a copy of each packet to any program that wants it.

Comment: I'm not aware of any relevant bugs in that.